# What is the right way to create reactivity (default) properties in Vuejs/Vuex?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuex

Im struggling to find the right equilibrium between creating default properties of an object and keeping them 'reactive'. Important note I am using Vuex for my store.

I already checked: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

However this does not seem to answer my question completely.

To give an good example of my problem:

In my 'store' I have products (json), containing contacts. Inside my application at some point new contacts are added to a product. For this I have an action.

```
const actions = {
  addContact: ({ commit }, payload) => {
    commit('ADD_CONTACT', payload)
  }
}
```

Which calls a mutation.

```
const mutations = {
  'ADD_CONTACT' (state, payload) {
    var contact = {'id': payload.contact.contactId, 'gender': payload.contact.gender, 'firstName': payload.contact.firstName, 'initials': payload.contact.initials, 'lastName': payload.contact.lastName, 'middleName': payload.contact.middleName, 'birthDay': payload.contact.birthDay, 'childern': []}
    state.products.find(function (product) {
      if (product.id === payload.product_id) {
        if (product.contacts) {
          product.contacts.push(contact)
        } else {
          Vue.set(product, 'contacts', [])
          product.contacts.push(contact)
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

As you can see I check if the product has an array of contacts, if it has not I create the array. Is this the correct way? Or does it make more sense to create an empty array in the first place, for example when adding a contact by defining an empty array 'childern'.

```
var contact = {'id': payload.contact.contactId, 'childern': []}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, you need to mention the properties in the state beforehand. Adding them later will surely add the property but it **won't** be reactive.

```
var contact = {'id': payload.contact.contactId, 'childern': []}
```

Is the way to go.

Somewhere in the [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) you posted

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of Object.observe), Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive.

The same applies for vuex stores.

Just for reference I once wanted to set my store to its default state so did something like this:

```
// someModule.js Don't copy this, this doesn't set to default state.
const state = {      
  testProps: {
    prop1: [],
    prop2: null
  }
}

const defaultState = {      
  testProps: {
    prop1: [],
    prop2: null
  }
}

const mutations = {
  mutationToSetState: (state, payload) => {
     state.testProps = payload
  },
  mutationToResetState: (state) => {
     state = defaultState // Please don't do this ever
  }
}
```

Here I expected the state to change, which indeed happened but at the same time it lost its reactivity. So suddenly no change detection for everything that depended on this state.

Comment: Thanks @Amresh Venugopal for the answer, however what if you do not know you have a childern array within a contact? Does this not make it strongly static by pre-defining all the 'data' elements?

Comment: If you post the state also with your question, I can look into it. So far in such cases (an array of objects) I have kept the array of objects as one of the properties in the state, it lets all the object elements to be reactive.